# How to package object prototypes in separate file

Tags: javascript

I have created a number of String.prototype functions which for maintainability I'd like to have in its own file.  That is, I'd like to include the file in a javascript project and thus have all the String functions defined.

I could create a module that exports each function, but then I'd have to assign each function as its own String prototype, yes?  Something like

```
var myStringFunctions = require("myStringFunctions");
String.prototype.func1 = myStringFunctions.func1;
```

Is there a way to include such a file so that the prototypes are defined as part of the inclusion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Try it**, you will see your code and using `require("./myStringFunctions");` works just fine.

**./myStringFunctions.js**

```
String.prototype.func1 = function() {
  return this.toUpperCase(this);
};
```

**./index.js**

```
require("./myStringFunctions");
console.log("foo".func1()); // FOO
```

Comment: You are correct, sir!  This works exactly as I had hoped.

Answer (score 0):

If your JS is going to run in the browser, you can use JS modules with the `import` and `export` syntax if you use a module bundling build tool like Webpack: https://webpack.js.org/ .

If your JS is running in a Node.js environment, modules are supported: https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_modules.asp